# Scroll tile map with joystick

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

In my game i am using tile map and sneaky joystick and I want to perform following task in my game.I am using box2d in my game.
I am create sprite body using box2d and also create static body for tile map.
My main problem is when my sprite moves that time tile map can not scroll.
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Cant understand exactly what is it you want help with ..? Can you elaborate your issue a bit .. ?

Comment: Can you give me your mail id than i send you whole code that i have issue.

Comment: @Shailesh_ios: In my game i am using joystick and tilemap in box2d game but sprite can not move using joystick. Code is long so it can not put here...

Comment: Have a look at my answer, Might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what code you are using for your joystick but, [Here's](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1418) what I used when I made use of joystick for my game. Its very simple to use and easy to understand. 
Hope that help you.. ! :)

Comment: I am using sneaky joystick. I am already done movement of tilemap and joystick and sprite only using cocos2d but when i am convert that logic into box2d at that time it not works. I want to show my code because i am new in iphone and game world so i need help.so please give me your id please help me please

Comment: You dont need to post the entire code, Just post the essentials.
What exactly is happening when you say it is not working..? Player does not move at all .. ? 
My Id  is in my profile.

Comment: One part of my game problem is found but dont know how to solve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738761/can-not-load-sprite-of-hudlayer is a link of my new question.